# MongoDB， How to associate array fields for statistics

Tags: mongodb

Example JSON：

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "g1"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "g2"
    }
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "item1",
      "gid": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "item2",
      "gid": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

How to associate two arrays and count ？I tried to use aggregate, I didn't get the results I wanted.

**Required Result:**
Or can directly find all the items associated with it, perfect....

```
{"groups": [
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "g1",
  "count": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "item1"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "name": "g2",
  "count": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "item2"
    }
  ]
}
]}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if, in your question, you add sample collection, the query you've already worked on, input and output expected from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
{$unwind:{
    path:"$groups",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
}},
{$unwind:{
    path:"$items",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
}},
{$redact: {$cond: [{
                    $eq: [
                           "$groups._id",
                           "$items.gid"
                         ]
                  },
                  "$$KEEP",
                  "$$PRUNE"
                ]
        }
},
{$project:{
    _id:1,
    groups_id:"$groups._id",
    group_name:"$groups.name",
    item_data:{
        _id:"$items._id",
        name:"$items.name",
        }
    }},
    {
        $group:{
            _id:"$groups_id",
            name:{$first:"$group_name"},
            count:{$sum:1},
            items:{$push:"$item_data"}
            }
    }
])
```

Comment: Two field arrays, similar to the association between the main table and the child table, "items.gid = groups._id" ..... then count?

Comment: Can you please provide an expected result?

Comment: Thanks, modified to "$eq: [$groups._id", "$items.gid"] ", works perfectly.